Android voice recorder waveform visualizer
I am developing a voice recorder for android,
I need to implement a waveform visualizer like google voice recorder app.
I got few code samples from GitHub to implement it.
the issue here is the waveform is not smooth like google voice recorder app.
Google voice recorder – each lines of the waveform moves smoothly
Google Voice Recorder
My voice reocrder app -  each lines are drawn at the same spot, which makes the waveform looks jittery.
My Voice Recordera
I got the below code from a open source project,  i need to optimize it to draw the waveform smoothly.
    private void drawRecordingWaveform(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        if (recordingData.size() > 0) {
            int recordingDataSize  = recordingData.size();
            int half = getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
            int width  = getWidth();

            float px = AndroidUtils.dpToPx(4);

            for (int i = 0; i < recordingDataSize; i++) {
                float startX = (float) viewWidth - i * px;
                float startY = half + recordingData.get(recordingData.size()-1 - i) + 1;
                float stopX = (float) viewWidth - i * px;
                float stopY = half - recordingData.get(recordingData.size()-1 - i) - 1;
                canvas.drawLine(startX,startY,stopX,stopY, waveformPaint);
            }


        }
    }


Not sure what you mean by "smooth". You may want to check solutions to posts when searching on: smooth canvas scrolling

If the waveform appears jittery because the amplitude data is very variable, you can apply a smoothing filter to your data?
Instead of drawing individual lines for each point, consider using a Path to create a continuous curve.
private void drawRecordingWaveform(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
if (recordingData.size() > 0) {
    int recordingDataSize = recordingData.size();
    int half = getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
    int width = getWidth();

    float px = AndroidUtils.dpToPx(4);
    Path path = new Path();
    
    // Start path at the first point
    float startX = width;
    float startY = half + recordingData.get(recordingDataSize - 1) + 1;
    path.moveTo(startX, startY);

    for (int i = 1; i < recordingDataSize; i++) {
        startX -= px;
        startY = half + recordingData.get(recordingDataSize - 1 - i) + 1;
        path.lineTo(startX, startY);
    }
    
    canvas.drawPath(path, waveformPaint);
}

}
